# Could you test for multiple expressions in statement 2 of a javascript for statement?

Tags: javascript

For example, can I do this:

```
for (var row = r-1; row < r+2, row < numRows, row >= 0; row++)
```

Comment: Yea... I'm trying to debug a problem and there's a lot going on so *I think* you could but I'm not sure.

Comment: The comma operator returns the value of the *last* operand, so this will work as long as `row >= 0` regardless of the other conditions. You're looking for `&&` instead of `,`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can, your attempt will have the same effect as just writing

```
for (var row = r-1; row >= 0; row++)
```

since the [**comma operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) only returns the result of the last expression. Maybe you want to use a [logical AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_.28&&.29) instead:

```
for (var row = r-1; row < r+2 && row && numRows && row >= 0; row++)
```

---

FYI, you can use *any* expression in each "section" in a `for` statement (almost, you can't directly use the `in` operator in the first section).